# create custom profile to run man using firejail

Tags: security, man, container, sandbox, firejail

I'm trying to use [`firejail`](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) (version 0.9.58.2) for application sandboxing on my `Debian Stable` machine.  From what I understand it's possible to create a custom configuration file for each application but I wasn't successful in doing so.

Currently I'm trying to write a custom `man.profile`-file, since it [sounds quite easy](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/building-custom-profiles/).  I put a file with the following content in my `~/.config/firejail/`-directory:

```
noblacklist /usr/share/man/
noblacklist /usr/lib/man-db/

include whitelist-var-common.inc

seccomp
shell none

private-bin sed,less,man,groff,nroff,tbl,bash
private-dev
```

But when I run `man less`, my pager opens only with an empty page and after closing I can read following error message:

```
Reading profile /home/$USER/.config/firejail/man.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Parent pid 42020, child pid 42045
7 programs installed in 10.65 ms
Child process initialized in 10.69 ms
/usr/bin/man: command exited with status 255: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t ISO-8859-1//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=189n -rLT=189n -Tutf8)
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any ideas/pointers are appreciated!

---

Update (thanks @@artem-s-tashkinov): when running `strace -f -e file -o /tmp/man.log man less` (after first performing `sudo firecfg --clean`) and examining the output of `/tmp/man.log` I found that several other files were read while invoking `man less`.  Therefore I updated the lines starting with `private-bin` and `private-lib` to include the following:

```
private-bin sed,less,man,groff,nroff,tbl,bash,terminfo,locale
private-lib /usr/lib/man-db,/usr/share/groff,/usr/share/locale,/usr/share/terminfo,/usr/share/man,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu,/usr/lib/charset.alias,/etc/ld.so.preload,/etc/ld.so.cache,/etc/manpath.config,/etc/suid-debug,/etc/terminfo,/etc/sysless,/etc/localtime
```

But the result is still negative: `man less` yields the following error:

```
bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory                                                                        
/usr/bin/man: command exited with status 127: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=189n -rLT=189n -Tutf8)
```

When looking for the location of `libtinfo.so.6` using `find /lib -name "*libtinfo*"` the result is in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, which is included in the `private-lib`-line.

And when eliminating the lines starting with `private-bin` and `private-lib`, it works (but obviously without the additional sandboxing).

Answer (score 1):

Run it via `strace -fF -e file -o /tmp/man.log man less` first to see which extra directories you need to include for the command to work under firejail.

At least on my Fedora 32 these additional directories are required:

- /usr/share/groff
- /usr/share/locale - this one is probably already included by `whitelist-var-common.inc`
- /usr/share/terminfo

Comment: @artem-s-tashkinov: thanks for the fast reply! I included the following line to my man.profile: `private-lib /usr/share/groff,/usr/share/locale,/usr/share/terminfo` but now I get a `WARNING: terminal is not fully functional` and it still only outputs an empty page.

Comment: A debian patch says these command currently don't work under firejail: https://sources.debian.org/patches/firejail/0.9.64-1/disable-terminal-tests.patch/ Or maybe you haven't whitelisted all the required directories.

Comment: @artem-s-tashkinov: well, that's a pity... I just figured out that I could run it without the `private-bin ...`-part of the file.  This defeats (partially) the sandboxing-idea, but it's a better option than not using firejail at all.

Comment: @artem-s-tashkinov: by the way: `strace` outputs `strace: deprecated option -F ignored`.

Comment: Old habits never die :-)